# How to create a new activity for each of the CardView in the Grid Layout that was created using onCreateView method and Adapters?

Tags: android, android-activity

Currently, I'm making a quiz app project for my University final exam course. I don't have any basics on Android development, so far I only followed tutorials online, particularly from this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRYxlKWXY5c&list=PLnfB3OWST3K3lEQmiRR6LhbqdgzTEy8_B&index=4

So, I have created a grid layout with its values, however it's not manually created one by one.

It's created by the onCreateView method

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);

    catView = view.findViewById(R.id.cat_grid);

    loadCategories();

    CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(catList);
    catView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

and by the help of CategoryAdapter.

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<CategoryModel> cat_list;

    public CategoryAdapter(List<CategoryModel> cat_list) {
        this.cat_list = cat_list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cat_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View myView;

        if(view == null){
            myView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cat_item_layout,viewGroup,false);
        }
        else{
            myView = view;
        }
        
        TextView catName = myView.findViewById(R.id.catName);
        catName.setText(cat_list.get(i).getName());
        return myView;
    }
```

Then, add the categories using loadCategories() method

```
private void loadCategories(){
    catList.clear();

    catList.add(new CategoryModel("1","Introduction"));
    catList.add(new CategoryModel("2","Learning Roadmap"));
    catList.add(new CategoryModel("3","Genomics"));
    catList.add(new CategoryModel("4","Metagenomics (coming soon)"));
    catList.add(new CategoryModel("5","Metabolomics (coming soon)"));
    catList.add(new CategoryModel("6","Proteomics (coming soon)"));
    catList.add(new CategoryModel("7","Transcriptomics (coming soon)"));
    catList.add(new CategoryModel("8","Epigenetics (coming soon)"));
    catList.add(new CategoryModel("9","Medical Informatics (coming soon)"));

}
```

What I want to do is that for each of those grid cards, it will open up different activities (since they are different topics).

I saw in a certain tutorial that we need to assign an id to each of the grid cards. But, in my case I don't know how, because I didn't create those cards manually and cannot click on the objects in the .xml file.

Does anyone know how to tackle this problem? Thank you very much beforehand.

[onCreateView Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oGsY.png)
[app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGM4L.png)

Unfortunately I haven't tried it myself, after searching online I couldn't find any reference.